# webclient request via authentication

Tags: asp.net, webclient

I'm calling a clients endpoint which "get" a json array.  Like so

```
 var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```

They are using authentication and i have the username and password. Is it possible to submit the username and password. Maybe i need to add custom headers? I can't find the exact examples for what i'm after

[image]

401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to specify your credentials:

```
var json = new WebClient { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, passwd) }.DownloadString(url);
```